# Get name of running process (Procfile) inside heroku

Tags: heroku

My Rails app on Heroku has a number of processes defined in the Procfile

Is there a way for an app to know what process name started it?

e.g. for Procfile:

```
web: rails s
job: run jobs
```

Is there an ENV variable (or similar) available within the running process to know if its `web` or `job`?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Why do you want this?

Comment: I am sending logs to an external service, want to tag the messages with the "app type" it is being sent from.

Might have two "web" type, each started with slightly different params.

Comment: That's not something your _application_ needs to do. Heroku log streams [already include this information](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval-via-cli-view-logs), e.g. see `app[web.1]`, `heroku[router]`, and `app[worker.1]` in this example.

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm a bit confused by your comment. Your question seems to ask how to know at runtime if a process is a `web` process, a `worker` process, etc., but your _comment_ says you might have 'two "web" type", each started with slightly different params'. What are you actually trying to learn at runtime? (And note that you likely _can't_ have two `web` processes defined with slightly different parameters, at least not as part of the same Heroku app. `web` processes are special in that they process inbound requests, and you only get one port to listen on.)

Comment: @Chris thats exactly it. I am using a different logging system that routes to an outside service (not via stdout). And want to send ```app[web.1]``` to the logs there.

Comment: As far as I know this should still work via a [log addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval-via-a-logging-add-on) or [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains). If it doesn't, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Chris we are not using a log addon but rather communicating directly to a log ingestion engine. 

In the case of Ruby on Rails, custom logger that sends data directly to an external service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Heroku sets up `DYNO` variable, as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables